# angular agora rtc how to audio mix?

Tags: javascript, angular, agora.io

Does this wrapper support audio mixing? I can't seem to find any examples. I need to implement the options on whether it loops and also how to control the volume.

Here on the Angular-Agora-RTC github page it explains that the second parameter for this function is for "audio: Indicates if this stream contains an audio track". However I can't find where to input the options for the audio track.

'''this.localStream = this.agoraService.createStream(uid, true, null, null, true, false);'''

Answer (score 0):

Use this community wrapper instead: [github.com/drew-thompson/ngx-agora](https://github.com/drew-thompson/ngx-agora) This community wrapper has better angular support and yes it can support audio mixing since the wrapper is based on v3.x of the base Web SDK.

Comment: Hey could you provide an example of audio mixing? I appreciate your response, if you cannot provide an example could you make your reply a comment. It is certainly not an answer to "how to audio mix".